# File download issue: comma in the file name in Struts 2

Tags: java, download, configuration, struts2, ognl

I have a file download functionality in my application (the type of file can be TXT, DOCX, PDF, etc.). When I upload a file (for example : `file A.pdf`), I can download the file normally (the file downloaded is `file A.pdf`). But if there's a comma in the file name (for example : `file,A.pdf`), the file downloaded is named `telechargerFichier.action` which is the name of my action.

Here is the key part of my `struts.xml` for downloading file :

```xml
<action name="telechargerFichier" class="documentAction" method="telechargerFichier">      
    <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
        <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
        <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `contentDisposition` property with dynamic result

```
<param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${fileName}"</param>
```

Now, create a getter in the action class for `fileName`

```
public String getFileName() {
  return fileName;
}
```